# Suppose $\varphi$ is a continuous complex valued function on a closed contour $\gamma$. Show function goes to $0$.

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

> Suppose $\varphi$ is a continuous complex valued function on a closed contour $\gamma$. Let $$F(z)=\int_{\gamma} \frac{\varphi(w)}{w-z}~dw$$ Show $\lim_{z\to\infty} F(z)=0$

We may bound:

$$\begin{align*}|F(z)|&\le \int_{\gamma} \left|\frac{\varphi(w)}{w-z}\right|~dw\\&\le M\int_{\gamma}\frac{1}{|w-z|}~dw\end{align*}$$

Then as $z\to\infty$, $\frac{1}{|w-x|}\to 0$ so $F(z)\to 0$.

Is this correct? Seems too trivial.

Comment: I'd say the bound $\;M\;$ depends on $\;\gamma\;$ and thus it could have an effect on that limit...

Comment: This is indeed correct.

Comment: @DonAntonio But $\gamma$ is fixed

Comment: @ZacharySelk Yep, that the variable of integration is $\;w\;$ misled me. Then yes: I think your proof is correct.

Comment: for $w \in \gamma$ : $\frac{1}{w-z} \to 0$ uniformly and so $\int_\gamma \frac{\varphi(w)}{w-z} dw \to 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\begin{align*}
|F(z)|&\le \int_{\gamma} \left|\frac{\varphi(w)}{w-z}\right|~dw\\&\le M\int_{\gamma}\frac{1}{|z-w|}~dw \le\frac{M\,\mathrm{length}(\gamma)}{\mathrm{dist}(z,\gamma)} =\frac{c}{\mathrm{dist}(z,\gamma)}.
\end{align*}
$$
So, if $\gamma\subset D(0,R)$, for some $R>0$, then
$$
|F(z)|\le \frac{c}{|z|-R}\to 0,
$$
as $z\to\infty$.